# android- Libgdx serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, android, serialization, libgdx

I have a `Player` class which records a players position and several other variables. Additionally in order to remember these states after the game is closed I attempted to serialize and deserialize my `player` object. This process works fine for the desktop version of my libGdx project however when I run it with my android device it fails (my coordinates are not saved). Furthermore when I check the "desktop" folder I can see the `"player.dat"` file however in my android folder its not there... At first I was thinking that maybe its something with the way I was debugging and saved the actual game on my phone and ran it, but even so the coordinates did not save.

Player class:

```
public class Player implements Serializable {

    private static final transient String defaultTexture = "data/libgdx.png";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    transient Texture texture;
    Vector2 position;
    String textureLoc;
    transient Sprite sprite;

    public Player (Vector2 position, String textureLoc){
        this.position = position;
        this.textureLoc = textureLoc;
    }

    public void loadContent() {
        if (Gdx.files.internal(textureLoc).exists())
            texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(textureLoc));
        else
            texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(defaultTexture));
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    }

    public void update(OrthographicCamera camera) {

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            Vector3 tp = new Vector3();
            tp.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(tp);
            if(tp.y > sprite.getY()){
                position.y += 4f;
            }else{
                position.y -= 4f;
            }
        }           
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.draw(texture, position.x, position.y);
    }

    public static void savePlayer(Player player) throws IOException {
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("player.dat");
        try {
            file.writeBytes(serialize(player), false);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Player readPlayer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Player player = null;
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("player.dat");
        player = (Player) deserialize(file.readBytes());
        return player;
    }

    private static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        return o.readObject();
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector2 position){
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter { 
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    Player player;
    SpriteBatch batch;  
    Vector2 position = new Vector2(50,50);
    boolean x = false;
    boolean y = false;  

    BitmapFont font;    

    @Override
    public void create () {     
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setScale(50f);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        player = new Player(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2), "data/mario.jpg");
        if(Gdx.files.local("player.dat").exists()){
            System.out.println("Player Exists. Reading File ...");

            x = true;
            try {
                player = Player.readPlayer();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }else{
            System.out.println("Player does not exist. Creating new player ...");
            y = true;

            player = new Player(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2), "data/mario.jpg");          
        }   

        player.loadContent(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
        player.update(camera);
        batch.begin();
        if(x){font.draw(batch, "Player Exists. Reading File ...", 20, 20);}
        if(y){font.draw(batch, "Player does not exist. Creating new player ...", 100, 100);}
        player.draw(batch);
        batch.end();        
    }

    public void dispose(){
        try {
            Player.savePlayer(player);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My only guess is that maybe there is some specifics to saving/getting serialized files on android, but even so I followed the libGdx API so it should have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone else in the future has the same problem what you have to do is also save the game state on `pause` as well as `dispose`. It turns out the serialization and deserialization process all works and the files are actually stored onto your device just fine. The main problem is that `dispose` only gets called when the phone manually kills the application NOT YOU :) So like I said also save the game state on pause and that is when you click the home button on your device. Ex:

```
 public void pause () { 
         try {
            Player.savePlayer(player);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
 }
```